# C++ Sphinx mismatch in inserted value vs queried value

Tags: c++, sphinx

Does Sphinx have a maximum length for string attributes? I insert the content of a document and when I query back the content, it differs from the inserted value (shortened).

Therefore, my question is does Sphinx check anything based on length, etc? The characters in the string are within my charset in the Sphinx config?

What am I doing wrong? Why is Sphinx truncating my inserted value? There is no error thrown when inserting the value in Sphinx, but querying it back directly results in a shortened string of the inserted value. (If I query the same string later, it is stills shortened?)

***Perhaps important, I use a real-time index***

**UPDATE**
The config I use places the content of the doc both in the index (to be searched) as in the attribute (to be queried back?): `rt_field` and `rt_attr_string`

**IMPORTANT**
Please note that I don't use the `sql_attr_field` which has a limit of 4MB per value (with an overal limit of 4GB?) as specified in the docs. I use the `rt_attr_string` which has no specified limit in the documentation? Do the same limits apply to `rt_attr_string`?

Comment: What does the Sphinx documentation say about it?

Comment: @paddy, thats the problem. I couldn't find anything specific in the documents? I read that there might be a limit on forums, but they don't specify any limits? Could you clarify this for me? The [doc](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current/conf-rt-attr-string.html) I refer to has no reference to any limit or what so ever?

Comment: @paddy, see my updates in the question? I still haven't been able to find any limits for `rt_attr_string`, as I was able to find for e.g. `sql_attr_field`